# clearInterval is not working properly on a progress bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm stuck on a very basic problem which I want to clear the interval when my progress is 100, but it doesn't stop.

```
  const clear = setInterval(() => {
      setProgress((prev) => prev + 1);
      if (progress > 99) {
        clearInterval(clear);
      }
    }, 10);
```

I can't see my mistake here.

Comment: what is the scope of `progress`?

Comment: @Greedo it's a react state

Comment: Probably your closure sees ("is bound to") an old version of progress. Would need more surrounding code to be sure.

Comment: Depending on how you use it [setInterval has some quirks](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/).

Comment: did you debug it? what did you find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine:

```js
const clear = setInterval(() => 
      setProgress((prev) => {
        if (prev >= 99) {
          clearInterval(clear);
        }
        return prev + 1
      }), 10);
```